# Which Django model fields won't raise IntegrityError if no input is given?

Tags: python, django, django-models

My initial thought was that if for any field `null=False`, then if the program does not specify a value for the field, IntegrityError will be raised for violating the NOT NULL constraint. I knew some fields such as CharField are an exception, but I tested this by adding a FileField to a model as `test = models.FileField()`, and not giving it any input. Saving the model did not raise any error.

So my question is, which model fields allow the program to save the model when no value or default is specified and `null=False`? I can't seem to find any comprehensive list online.

Comment: did you call `model.full_clean()` before saving?

Comment: @WilliamBright No I didn't. I'm not familiar with that command, what would it do in this case?

Comment: it would run the validators in the fields and model to check it conforms to what you want the data to be "shaped" as. Meaning, if you want `null = False` then Django won't really verify it UNLESS you call `full_clean`. Its a quirk from a past era.

Comment: Yes this works for me, the message given from the command says that FileField cannot be blank, not null, even though `null=False`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1 - You should not be confusing `null` with `blank`

- `null` means that no value was specified for the field. If `null=False` then you have to specify a value for the field

```
    title = models.CharField(null = False)
    ......
    item = Item(.....)
    item.save() # won't save 
    item = Item(....., title='hello world')
    item.save() # will save
```

- `blank` means that the value of the field exists but it is empty. If `blank=Flase` then you must provide at least a non empty value.

```
    title = models.CharField(blank= False)
    item = Item(.....)
    ......
    item.save() # won't save
    item = Item(....., title='')
    item.save() # won't  save
    item = Item(....., title='hello world')
    item.save() # will save
```

2 - `FileField` and `ImageField` are all saved as a string in database, and you can add `null=False` or `blank=False` to make them required just like you do with `CharField`.

```
file = models.FileField(null=False, blank=False)
```

You can even add more constraints, such as file extension and file size, using `validators`.